# Draw Rectangle in View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to draw a rectangle in my ViewController2.

I read that I can use CGRect but I can't find how to do it.

I want to represent a room, so i can place a dot in the position where i am in the room.

I've already tried to override drawRect method but i had some errors

[image]

I tried with this code:

```
 // rectangle.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Rectangle : UIView 
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect myRect; 
@end

// rectangle.m
#import "rectangle.h"
@implementation Rectangle
@synthesize myRect;

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
 // Drawing code here.
 CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);
 CGContextFillRect(c, myRect);
}
@end

// ViewController2.m
 #import "ViewController2.h"
#import "rectangle.h"
@implementation ViewController2

 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 if(![self.view isKindOfClass:Rectangle])
 {
     Rectangle *view = [[Rectangle alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
     self.view = view;
 }
 [(rectangle*)self.view setMyRect:CGRectMake(120, 120, 80, 80)];
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: Please do a minimal amount of homework before asking a basic question.

Comment: I modified your code listed, try that.  I wasn't sure that your `self.view` was your custom view class (could be set in IB, no idea).  Put a breakpoint in your custom view's drawing code and see if it gets called.  Go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't think you understand CGRect is a struct and not an object. It defines a rectangles point of origin and size which you need to then use with a UIView or another UI class.

Drawing a rect as @user2277872 has indicated takes a CGRect as its frame - Assigning it's point of origin in the view (x.y) and it's width and height (w,d)

to get that on to your view controller view you'll need to add it as a subview.

> CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400);
>
> then do UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

again as @user2277872 has indicated you can do this in the viewdidload method

only think he didn't tell you is that you should the write

```
[self.view addSubview: v];
```

another point to note is the view is usually white by default so you'll need to set the background colour if you want to see it

```
[v setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
```

You should see a rectangle at the top of the view.

As you're using storyboards you could just drag a view on to the view controller and set it's colour and size there.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `-(void) viewDidLoad` method within the `.m` file, do:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h) 
// you substitute x,y,w, and h for x position, y position, width, and height
```

then do:

```
 UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

And that's how you use `CGRectMake` in code.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In a view controller there are many ways to draw a rectangle (in code).  You can create a CAShapeLayer and add it to your view.  You can override the `drawRect:` function and use core graphics to draw.  You can create a GLView that draws a rectangle.  You can create a single UIView subview with a borderColor and borderWidth.

There are many options.  We need to know the purpose and the desired effect to give you the best course of action.  A little more backstory and things you have tried would be very helpful in giving you a valid solution.

Comment: @Carioni You say you tried `drawRect` but had some errors.  Post the code you tried and we can resolve the errors.  Until then we can only give you broad ideas, not actual solutions.